# Easy function to commatize a number in string in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

To add commas to a number in string, can there be a simple function for common situation use? I found one method but it seems very complex though comprehensive: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Commatizing_numbers#Racket

I simply want to have a function which works as follows:

```
(addcommas 1234567890)
"1,234,567,890"
```

(It is slightly surprising that Racket, which has many high level functions, does not have a built-in function for this common requirement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
(define (addcommas n)
  (define (split n acc)
    (if (< (abs n) 1000)
        (cons n acc)
        (let-values ([(quot rem) (quotient/remainder n 1000)])
          (split quot (cons (abs rem) acc)))))
  (apply ~a (split n '()) #:separator ","))

(addcommas -2332342390)

;; -> "-2,332,342,390"
```

If you want to format real numbers, since they have a binary representation, and the conversion can be imprecise, you have to add a precision parameter which specifies the number of digits after the point:

```
(define (addcommas-real n precision)
  (let* ((int-part (exact-truncate n))
         (float-part (exact-truncate (* (-  n int-part) (expt 10 precision)))))
    (~a (addcommas int-part) "." (abs float-part))))

(addcommas-real -2332342390.34 2)

;; -> "-2,332,342,390.34"

(addcommas-real -2332342390.34 5)

;; -> "-2,332,342,390.34000"
```

Comment: Can the function be simplified if values which will be sent are always positive?

Comment: Simply remove the two `abs` call.

Comment: I believe handling decimal point will make it much more complex.

Comment: I'll change the answer.

Comment: Best will be to keep this simpler form also and give decimal point-abled form as a separate function. Thanks for your time and interest.

Comment: @mso, just a gentle reminder to mark an answer as accepted if (and only if) it solves the problems of the question; this is both for other people landing on this page from google searches, to give evidence that the answer solves the problem or not, and it is also useful to keep people motivated to answer to your questions.